# gdb.printing not available in python2

Tags: python, gdb

First of all, let me start out by saying, I am using gdb version 7.7 built --with-python

the python version is 2.6.x

And ***No*** I cannot upgrade them, since I'm limited by the devtools specifically meant for debugging my companies code.

There a lot of useful gdb-python scripts but all of them require me to

```
import gdb.printing
```

But I get an import error

```
(gdb)python import gdb.printing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: No module named printing
Error while executing Python code.
```

Is there any way to get the gdb.printing module in this version of gdb and python? (python3 works fine).

I would really appreciate any inputs for this.

Comment: In the "good" gdb, run `python import gdb.printing; print (gdb.printing.__file__)` to find where the module is located. Then run `python print(sys.path)` in both the good and bad gdb to see where they're looking for modules. You probably just need to add a directory to `sys.path` when using bad gdb.

Comment: One possible cause of this problem is when gdb is built from source and you try to run the gdb that is in the build directory. For everything to work correctly, `make install` should be done and gdb should be run from its installed location (`/usr/local/bin/gdb`, for example, which is where gdb gets installed if no `--prefix` option was given when it was built).

Comment: Its not really an install problem I am facing. I have multiple gdb's and I am forced to use the old one.

Comment: I installed gdb 7.7 from source a few days ago, and it can load its own `gdb.printing` module, from `/usr/local/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py`. See if the procedure in my first comment allows you to load `gdb.printing` from one of your other gdb installations. Or, if your gdb is installed at `/path/bin/gdb`, see if there's a `/path/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py` file.